# Is there a way to override a template method matching only when two template parameters are the same?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function call:

```
template <typename A, typename B> bool foo();
```

I would like to override it so that any calls where A and B are the same type go to a special function override.  I'm thinking of something like:

```
template<typename A>
    bool foo<A,A>() 
      { return false; }
```

However, this code does not compile, and I can't find any code that might work.  My recourse so far has been to explicitly override all possible types:

```
template<> bool foo<class1,class1>() { return false; }
template<> bool foo<class2,class2>() { return false; }
template<> bool foo<class3,class3>() { return false; }
```

but this is inelegant and requires maintenance when new classes are brought in.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Edit:
To be clear, when A is not the same type as B, I have code like this:

```
 template<typename A, typename B> 
 bool foo() {
    Thing<A,B> instance;  // Thing<A,A> is never legal and will not compile
 }
```

(The code gets called because I'm trying all possible combinations of B against A and vice-versa. I was hoping to deal with this easily with the compiler, rather than implement if-then tests on every B to make sure it doesn't match A. Maybe there's a better way of doing this, but I thought this design would be elegant.)

Comment: Function template partial specializations do not exist. You will need to use SFINAE in one form or another to achieve similar results. I am not exactly well versed in that right now, but `std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<T1, T2>>` is a starting point (syntactic/semantic issues aside in this).

Answer (score 8):

Your attempt does not compile because partial function template specialization (`template<typename A> bool foo<A,A>()`) is not allowed. The usual workaround is to use overloading, as template parameters often occur as function parameters. In your case (no function parameters), if C++17 is available, you can use `if constexpr`  together with the `<type_traits>` header, e.g.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename A, typename B> bool foo()
{
   if constexpr (std::is_same_v<A, B>)
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
```

Comment: This won't work because I actually need to execute code in the other case, code which cannot be instantiated. I need to return false if the same, but do something if true, and the 'do something' won't compile.

Comment: @NathanielTagg: *Normal If* won't work, but *Constexpr If* does, because it **discards** the branch not executed: https://godbolt.org/z/GZvqYZ (compiles and returns 2 despite the fact that thing<bool,bool> cannot be instantiated - the else is discarded in that case)

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have access to C++17 and `if constexpr`, you can simply use standard SFINAE:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename A, typename B, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<A, B>{}, int> = 0> 
bool foo() { return true; }

template <typename A, typename B, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<A, B>{}, int> = 0> 
bool foo() { return false; }
```

Comment: I usually try to avoid the word "simple" together with SFINAE, but anyway, +1 :)